# different db provider without recompile my dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i am working on asp.net mvc app now.
I want to put all db logic to my mydbprovider.dll

The problem is in design, how can i change only db provider name in my web.config without recompile my own dll ? 
I will use such .net providers as (oracle,mssql,postrgree)

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as soon as you change the web.config then the site's appDomain will restart. This is unavoidable and only happens in the following scenarios:

- Change of web.config
- change to bin folder
- Trigger of
  numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart

what you need to do to be able to swap dal layers easily is to program to interfaces. There will be an interface that implements with the correct methods that you want to use and then any associated dal layer (mysql, sqlserver, oracle) will implement those methods

hopefully that will mean you are not bound to a specific implementation of a dal

paul

Comment: Thanks, i understand that i must stop iis. I just want to know what the best practice when u need many providers without change dll code

Comment: Two words: "Dependency Injection".

Comment: 100% agree with @RPM1984 - my understanding of the question was incorrect :(